# How to declare a global variable that holds the element in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

How to declare a global variable that holds the complete element.
eg:Hi Hello
the variable tha declared should hold the data element.

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as putting:

```
<xsl:variable name="myvariable" />
```

at the top of your XSLT script (or the bottom, I guess it doesn't matter).

You can set an initial value with

```
<xsl:variable name="myvariable" select="'somevalue'" />
```

if you want. Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_variable.asp for a bit more info.

Comment: thnk you mark but i need to hold the element as value. Eg: <data>Hi hello</data>